# Having trouble testing model validation with Laravel

Tags: unit-testing, testing, laravel, laravel-4, tdd

I'm just starting out with TDD and I'm trying to test validation in a model.  Currently, all my tests pass, but I believe that they shouldn't.  The testBodyIsRequiredToValidate() should fail since I have not added it to the rules array.  When I remove the title required from the rules array, all my tests fail as expected.  However, adding title required causes them all to pass.

My Tests:

```
class PostTest extends TestCase {

    public function testTitleIsRequiredToValidate()
    {
        $post = new Post;
        $post->body = 'foobar';

        $this->assertFalse($post->validate(compact('post')));
    }

    public function testBodyIsRequiredToValidate()
    {
        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = 'foobar';

        $this->assertFalse($post->validate(compact('post')));
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function validate($input)
    {
        $rules = array(
            'title' => 'required'
        );

        $v = Validator::make($input, $rules);

        if ($v->passes()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is it because you are using `assertFalse` instead of `assertTrue`?

Comment: I'm using `assertFalse` because the validation should return `true` so that the test will initially fail, since I have not required the body in the model's code, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your validation is wrong. You pass the model itself to the validator but you should pass an associative array.

- When you delete `title` from the rules you pass an empty rule, so the validation will be always true, thats why all your test fail.
- When you add `title` to your rules, the validations will be always false hence all your tests pass, because the validator's first parameter doesn't have an array element called `title`.

One way to correct this is to change your validation line to this:

```
$v = Validator::make(array('title' => $input['post']->title), $rules);
```

Here you get the `$post` from your `$input` array, because [`compact()`](http://php.net/compact) will put it to an array with the key of the variable name. Then you access the `title` property of the object and make this to the value of the `title` key so the validator will be able to find and validate it.

I have to mention that your validation technique is kinda bad for me. You pass the object in an array to a function of the same object. Why don't you get the object in the function?

I would write the validator function like this:

```
public function validate() {
    $rules = array(
        'title' => 'required'
    );

    $v = Validator::make($this->toArray(), $rules);

    return $v->passes();
}
```

So I could call the function like this in the tests:

```
$this->assertFalse($post->validate());
```